# Slow browser cache with jquery/ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, firebug, browser-cache

I am investigating a problem with jQuery, Ajax and browser caches.

We're using jQuery to get a piece of html from the server via Ajax. When this is not cached, it takes about 10ms to respond (according to Firebug). It does not matter if this is a 200 or a 304 response. When the browser doesn't go to the server (which I see in Firebug by the grey lines and the cache response headers), FireBug reports a 'waiting' time of over 200ms.

Anybody got hints on what is wrong here?

Edit: It is probably Firebug that's slowing the cache down. Closing Firebug gives a much snappier page.

Comment: Have you undertaken any other measures to increase "snappiness"? Because I am having problems with all browsers (apart from firefox) to get fast response times consistently...

Comment: Closing FireBug helped improve the snappiness in FireFox, others browsers didn't show any problems. So we did not take any measures.

Comment: @Erik Horlings : please validate an answer

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the speed of your computer, to look for the suitable information in the whole of your web browser cache.

When data are not in your web browser cache, the data is immediatly found from the server. When data are in your web browser cache, it takes time to search the correponding data among all data in your web browser cache.

Comment: I'm working on a Core i5 with 8G memory running Ubuntu 12.04. SO computer speed should not be a problem.

Comment: I have almost the same configuration and observe this